# Get term count on a category page

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode

I want to display a count of items in my header, a count of how many items are in the current category...

Example:
User goes to "T Shirts" > in the header it says "20 Items" --- They go to "Hoodies" > Header says "10 Items"

I'm currently using a shortcode and code in functions.php:

```php
add_shortcode( 'products-counter', 'products_counter' );
function products_counter( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( [
        'category' => '',
    ], $atts );

    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
    if ( is_numeric( $atts['category'] ) ) {
        $cat = get_term( $atts['category'], $taxonomy );
    } else {
        $cat = get_term_by( 'slug', $atts['category'], $taxonomy );
    }

    if ( $cat && ! is_wp_error( $cat ) ) {
        return $cat->count;
    }
    return '';
}
```

Which works great if I define the product category in the shortcode... My issue is it's in the header, so all category pages say the same item count... Is there a way to get it to display based on url?

Comment: Note that WooCommerce dev support and other 3rd party plugins are off topic here, however, this question can be phrased in generic terms

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding shortcode you have to add the hook which is on the product category page:

```
 
// Use this hook for working directly on category page
// add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'show_category_product_counts', 10 );
// Use this shortcode hook if you want to put on anywhere in the category page if you are using Elementor/WPBakery
add_shortcode( 'product_cat_count', 'show_category_product_counts', 10);
function show_category_product_counts( ) {
        // Return if it is product archive/Shop page
        if( !is_product_category())
            return false;
        // Get product category object
        $category = get_queried_object();
        $categoryId = $category->term_id;
        $term = get_term( $categoryId, 'product_cat' ); 
        echo 'Product Category: '
            . $term->name . ' ('
            . $term->count
            . ' Items)';
    }
```

Please add this code to your active theme's `function.php` file.
It will show the product category count on the category page after the category title.

Note: You can make changes in the last line in the function to print the text.

Comment: I'm using Elementor page builder so this doesn't work - anyway to shortcode this at all so the output can be placed anywhere?

Comment: Oky, then do one thing use this method `show_category_product_counts()` for `add_shortcode()` hook. This will work.

Comment: Replace the above `add_action()` with `add_shortcode( 'product_cat_count', 'show_category_product_counts');` and use the shortcode in elemeter as `[product_cat_count]`. This solution will work for the shortcode.

Comment: I have updated my code above. Please use that shortcode to use it in Elementor.

Comment: No luck... It just showed blank space - it could be because I'm using custom loops and not WooCommerce templates?

Comment: Can you please share screenshot where are you writing this shortcode? If you are using this in PHP template you have to use `do_shortcode('[product_cat_count]')` hook to work perfectly.

Comment: @BaikareSandeep your code is trying to be copy pasta, a good answer explains why and how so that the person asking the question understands the solution. This answer does not explain what the code does or why it works. Also `$term` and `$category` are the same object, half the lines in the code can be removed as they duplicate work already done

Comment: @AaronBradford using custom loops completely changes the situation, this is a super critical piece of info you should add to your question, along with information about those loops and how they are implemented, If I understand correctly, the solution to this problem will not work for you because of this, and your custom loops should be replaced with `pre_get_posts` filters

Answer (score 0):

Put this Code On Your Header and Check It is a working On Your header

```
<?php 

  if (is_tax('product_cat')) {

    $category = get_queried_object();
                        
    $get_id = $category->term_id;
                        
            echo do_shortcode('[products_counter category="'.$get_id.'" ]');

    } 

?>
```

functions.php

```
function products_counter( $atts ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( [
        'category' => '',
    ], $atts );

    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';

    if ( is_numeric( $atts['category'] ) ) {
        $cat = get_term( $atts['category'], $taxonomy );
    } else {
        $cat = get_term_by( 'slug', $atts['category'], $taxonomy );
    }

    if ( $cat && ! is_wp_error( $cat ) ) {
        return $cat->count;
    }
    return '';
}
add_shortcode('products_counter','products_counter');
```

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to put in the main post that I'm using Elementor page builder so PHP is not an option for me - Shortcodes are fine though

Comment: @AaronBradford your question has no mention of Elementor, you need to edit your question to reflect what you're actually asking or people will answer the question you wrote, not the question you meant. Also keep in mind that Elementor and other 3rd party plugins are off topic here

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a term archive, such as a tag page, or a category page, you can retrieve that term like this:

```php
$term = get_queried_object();
```

And show the count like this:

```php
$count = $term->count;
```

Keep in mind however that:

- Custom queries will override this and interfere. `get_queried_object` always uses the main query
- `get_queried_object` will only return a term on term archives. If you use it on an author archive you will get a `WP_User` object instead. Always check for this or you'll encounter errors